# AS3 with box2d weird effect during falling in a platformer game

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, velocity, horizontal-scrolling

I am making a platformer game using AS3 and box2D. I have a weird problem that I cant figure out. The character is constantly running, on touch it jumps - pretty standard. But when it's jumping from a high point, the character looses horizontal velocity during falling under gravity and moves only on the Y axis until it touches the ground and then resumes the running. The weird thing is, that if I decrease the gravity there is no such effect. I tried playing with density, friction. Also there is no damping.

I googled every possible box2d problem related to jumping and falling and velocity issues. Couldn't find anything.

Here is the code for the character movement. Gravity is 20, timestep is 1/15.

```
public class HeroModel extends GameObjectModel
{
    public var isJumping:Boolean = false;
    public var isAlive:Boolean = true;
    public var forwardForce:b2Vec2;
    public var decreasingForceY:Number = -200;
    public var decreasingForceX:Number = 100;
    public var startPos:Point;
    public var jumps:Number = 1;

    public function HeroModel()
    {
        super();
    }


    override public function initFrom(initObj:Object, world:b2World):void
    {
        super.initFrom(initObj, world);

        var filterdata:b2FilterData = new b2FilterData();
        filterdata.groupIndex = 1;
        filterdata.maskBits = 1;
        physicsBody.GetFixtureList().SetRestitution(0);
        physicsBody.GetFixtureList().SetDensity(0);
        physicsBody.GetFixtureList().SetFriction(0);
        physicsBody.GetFixtureList().SetFilterData(filterdata);
        physicsBody.SetType(b2Body.b2_dynamicBody);
        physicsBody.SetBullet(true);

        applyForwardForce();
        physicsBody.SetUserData(this);
        startPos = new Point(this.physicsBody.GetPosition().x, this.physicsBody.GetPosition().y);
    }

    public function die():void
    {
        //TODO Empty function.?
    }

    public function applyForwardForce():void
    {
        forwardForce = new b2Vec2(200,0);
        physicsBody.ApplyForce(forwardForce, new b2Vec2(0,0));
    }

    public function jump(e:EnterFrameEvent):void
    {

        if(decreasingForceY < 0 && decreasingForceX > 75)
        {
            physicsBody.ApplyImpulse(new b2Vec2(decreasingForceX, decreasingForceY), new b2Vec2(0,0));
            decreasingForceY+=5;
            decreasingForceX-=2.5;
        }

    }

    public function resetVelocity():void
    {
        decreasingForceX = 100;
        decreasingForceY = -200;
    }

}
```

[image: screenshot]

This is a screenshot from the game. The red is what happens, and the green is what I want.

Any ideas where am I mistaken? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with using SetLinearVelocity, now it's all good. :)

```
   public function jump(e:EnterFrameEvent):void
    {
        if (!singleJump)
        {
            physicsBody.IsAwake();
            physicsBody.IsBullet();



            physicsBody.SetLinearVelocity(new V2(75, -200));



            physicsBody.GetLinearVelocity();
            trace(physicsBody.GetLinearVelocity().x);
            trace(physicsBody.GetLinearVelocity().y);

            singleJump = true;
```

Comment: I don't get it :D I am the author, and I am just saying that instead of using ApplyImpuse, I found out that SetLinearVelocity fixes the issue.

Comment: I have deleted the comment, my bad! I should have analyzed that author is same! please add one line of code how you have fixed it to make you answer more appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

Gravity of 20 is big (8 or 9 is more natural). The motion/reaction you describe fits with the gravity used applied to a big object like a bus or a big truck. My guess is that your character might actually be as big as a bus or a truck. Since I don't see anywhere in your code a scale factor being used that seems like a good assumption. Skipping scale factor might make everything simpler but it can't make your simulation realistic.

Box2D MUST be used with a scalefactor, its measure unit is in meter so a 100x100 object is a big building.

Comment: I like your logic and I am playing around with that now. A few other things came to my mind. I tried setting the hero to be 1x1 pixels, but it did not change anything. I guess that is because I use dragon bones for the character. Then I tried setting the mass directly with this code

 `var massData = new b2MassData(); physicsBody.GetMassData(massData); 
massData.mass = 20.0 // or whatever; 
physicsBody.SetMassData(massData);`
I can feel the mass is changing, but still I get the bad effect. Now I will try the scale factor that you are suggesting.